# code for function that takes in list of integers and returns True if contains 007 in order

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the question written more simply:

I'm trying to write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order. The sequence 0, 0, 7 does not necessarily have to appear in consecutive order in the array for True to be returned.  For example,  spy_game([1,0,2,4,0,5,7]) should return True.

But, I need guidance as it won't work as is below.

```
def spy_game(nums):
    for x in range(0,len(nums)):
        first_0=nums.index(0)
        second_0=nums.index(0)
        seven=nums.index(7)
        if first_0!=second_0 and first_0<second_0 and nums[first_0:second_0+1]!=seven and seven>second_0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Any help revising my code in the way I'm trying to complete the exercise would be great.

Thanks.

edit--
Based on feedback here, I revised the code as the following:

```
def spy_game(nums):
    for x in range(0,len(nums)):
        first_0=nums.index(0)
        second_0=nums.index(0, first_0+1)
        seven=nums.index(7)
        if nums[first_0:second_0+1]!=seven and seven>second_0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

This works.

Comment: ...you get the same index of the fist 0 twice...

Comment: would [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7] be true? would [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,7]?

Comment: Have you done any debugging at all?

Comment: @Patrick Artner, yes to both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.index` as written will find the same zero twice.  `.index` takes an offset to start looking, so start one after the first zero:

```
    first_0 = nums.index(0)
    second_0 = nums.index(0,first_0 + 1)
```

Comment: Mark, thank you.  I revised the code as you indicated and then removed 'first_0!=second_0 and first_0<second_0' from the if statement and it worked.  I didn't realize that 'nums.index(0)' will be treated as the same value in an array even if one of them was assigned as different names, "first_0" and "second_0".  So, now I understand the way they are differentiated is by stating that one will be searched for after the first one is found using  .index

Answer (score 0):

Your basic logic is faulty.  You locate the first `0` twice, and then locate the first `7`.  This guarantees that your check will fail as `first_0` *must* be equal to `second_0`.  You've done nothing to attend to the numbers being in that order.

Instead, once you find that first `0`, you have to check *only* the *remainder* of the list for another `0`.  If you find that, then you check the list after that *second* `0` to see whether there's a `7` down there.

If you succeed with all three digits, you return `True`, but return `False` on any failure.

Coding that is left as an exercise for the student.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what exactly you want to achieve. I think you want to check whether `[0,0,7]` is a (non-consecutive) sub-sequence of `numbers`?

Maybe you want to do something like this?

```
def spy_game(numbers, target=(0,0,7)): 
    if len(target) == 0: 
        return True 
    try: 
        i = numbers.index(target[0]) 
    except ValueError: 
        return False 
    return spy_game(numbers[i+1:], target[1:])
```